# Supabase with Next.js 13 App Router OAuth not logging in

Tags: next.js, oauth, supabase

Whenever I log in with

```js
  // twitch signin handler
  const handleTwitchSignIn = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "twitch",
      options: {
        redirectTo: `${location.origin}/${lang}/auth/callback`,
      },
    });
  };

  // google signin handler
  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "google",
      options: {
        redirectTo: `${location.origin}/${lang}/auth/callback`,
      },
    });
  };
```

I don't get any "code" param back that is supposed to be redirected into `/auth/callback`.

None of the doc seems to talk about this. I see the cookie value being the code-verifier, but the code itself is missing from the url.

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours reading PKCE and going through the `auth-helper-nextjs` library code but couldn't find the correct answer.

It turns out, you simply have to add a Redirect URL policy in Supabase console.
Also, you can see mine has language dynamic url due to i18n enabled.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, but whitelisting Redirect URLs didn't help. I'm still not getting the code back from Supabase after a successful auth from the OAuth provider.

Comment: @JordanF have you checked your callback router?

Comment: I figured it out @Seho. Thanks. I was mixing up PKSE with the implicit OAuth flows. Setting it explicitly as PKSE on the outlink to Google worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the supabase-js client library, you can call the signInWithOAuth() method:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({ provider: 'google' })
```

> Note: The data that you receive will contain the url, that you'll be have to redirect to from server side (if you're using SSR auth with PKCE flow)

[Output of signInWithOAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIQDH.png)

```
    return redirect(data.url)
```